# Handle subscription changes in meteor react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

so this is my first question ever on StackOverflow but I have a question that's been on my mind for a while now.

Before, when I used Blaze in Meteor it was easy to handle subscription changes. Now when I've switched to React it has become a little bit more tedious but still manageable.

The only problem I have so far is how to handle changes to the subscription which occurs in a child component.
The code below is what I've come up with but it doesn't work that well since it causes a complete wipe of the local collection and it doesn't feel smooth in the UI.
I handle the change of the child via a function passed in props that sets a ReactiveVar which is then passed to the subscription.

Is there a better way? A best practice?

```
const DataComponent = props =>
  (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const { currentChildVal, handleChildClick } = props;
          const newVal = currentChildVal === 'someDefaultValue' ? 'newValue' : 'someDefaultValue';
          // Pass a new value to the parent
          handleChildClick(newVal);
        }}
      />
      {
        // Render the data
      }
    </div>
  );

// The ReactiveVar that the child will be provided
const fromChild = new ReactiveVar('someDefaultValue');

const DataContainer = withTracker(({ fromProp }) => {

  const currentChildVal = fromChild.get(); // Getting current value
  // and passing it to the sub
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('sub', fromProp, fromChild.get());
  const data = Collection.find().fetch();

  // function passed to the child
  const handleChildClick = (newVal) => {
    fromChild.set(newVal);
  };

  return {
    loading: !handle.ready(),
    data,
    currentChildVal,
    handleChildClick,
  };
})(DataComponent);
```

Comment: I think you want to use component *state* here. You're trying to pass the state of the child component to the parent aren't you?

Comment: Can you post a piece of your old code to see what happened before?